# How to use /K in visual studio code terminal call?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

> How to use "/K" command for terminal call from visual studio while running python code run in terminal

%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\shuvagho\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\shuvagho\Anaconda3

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **shellArgs** parameter in the **settings.json** like this:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/K", "conda activate"],

"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false,
```

If Anaconda was initialized properly via *"conda init"*, you should have *"..\Anaconda3\condabin"* on your system path and the *conda.bat* will be found w/o further specification.

The last parameter disables the automatic activation, since this is now done directly with every terminal start.